# PrettyFaces redirects friendly URL to unfriendly URL, I would like to keep friendly URL

Tags: jsf, url-rewriting, spring-webflow, prettyfaces

I have to add some SEO functionality for my site. Site is based on Spring Webflow with JSF, PrettyFaces and Promefaces.

I made URL like `/Hanover/100+300`. Everything is working OK. Prettyfaces redirected from this URL to `/app/tyres` with query params to parameters in bean.

But I need to keep and see URL with first state. like `/Hanover/100+300...` without redirecting it.

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks!

pretty-faces.xml

```
<url-mapping id="search">
    <pattern value="/search/#{searchtype}/#{city}/#{dimens}" />

    <view-id value="/app/tyres" />
</url-mapping>
```

webflow.xml

```
<flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
    <flow-execution-listeners>
        <listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
    </flow-execution-listeners>
</flow-executor>

<flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
    <flow-location-pattern value="/**/flow.xml" />
</flow-registry>

<faces:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices"/>  

<beans:bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener"/>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>5000000</max-file-size>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/search/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/main/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

part of servlet-context.xml

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <beans:property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
    <beans:property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
    <beans:property name="flowUrlHandler" ref="customDefaultUrlhandler"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="customDefaultUrlhandler" class="de.tyresnow.web.utils.CustomDefaultFlowUrlHandler"/>

<flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry"/>
```

Comment: Just don't redirect then?

Comment: in summary i wanna have hamed states like /app/tyres/state1 /app/tyres/state2 /app/tyres/state3. not like /app/tyres?execution=e1s2 /app/tyres?execution=e1s3 /app/tyres?execution=e1s4

Comment: I know. By default URL rewriters like PrettyFaces should merely forward not redirect. So perhaps you misconfigured it to redirect instead of forward.

Comment: Could you include your configuration in the question?

Comment: looking forward: if forward not possible. somebody could show another way?